# How to get the ng-model of inputs appended to the form to have their own scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the below directive. The directive attribute goes on a counter button and adds a text input element to my form each time the incrementer button is clicked. Each added input takes text input independently until I add the ng-model to the directive's template. Then when I type in one input they all update together.

How can I get the directive to give each added input it's own scope while still using the same ng-model='equipment.equipment_name' for all of them?

Additionally the counter button to add inputs and the space for those respective inputs sits in an ng-repeat itself. So in the same form I display multiple types of equipment. A user may in turn have multiple instances of any one type of equipment. I need them to be able to assign a unique name to each instance of any type.

```
myApp.directive('addinputs', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope ,element) {

      //binds to a button intended to add text inputs to my form
      element.bind('click', function () {

        //refers to a div that has a binding to a counter value
        var resourceParents = document.getElementsByClassName('count');

        //initial number of inputs needed to get names for the resource category
        var resourceChildren = 0;

        //References multiple resource categories where inputs will be added
        var childId = 'space-for-inputs' + scope.$index;

        //Updates the count for the number of inputs needed
        for (var i = 0; i < resourceParents.length; i++) {
          resourceChildren += parseInt(resourceParents[i].innerHTML);
        };

        var inputTemplate = "<div class='\resource-name-input input_wrapper\'><input ng-model='\equipment.equipment_name\' type='\text\' name='\textInput\'></div>"

        //adds the new input above the previous
        angular.element(
            document.getElementById(childId))
            .append($compile(inputTemplate)(scope)
        );

        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new scope by calling `scope.$new()` and passing that into the `$compile` statement. But I don't think that will do what you want. Take a look into this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3akOBkrR41XYdakfGkEW?p=preview).

It creates a `inputs` array on the scope and adds an input object each time the button is pressed. The view does a `ng-repeat` over each input and renders out the `input` element with it's own scope. (The scope is automatically generated because I used `ng-include` in this example).

Comment: this is a nice solution. I have just one additional related problem. I should have mentioned in the original question that the button to add inputs and the space for those respective inputs sits in an ng-repeat itself. So in the same form I display multiple types of equipment. A user may in turn have multiple instances of any one type of equipment. I need them to be able to assign a unique name to each instance of any type. As is this adds inputs to all types of equipment in the form. I'll revise my original post with this info.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an array to store data of multiple input element.
Please have look at my update here: http://jsfiddle.net/53m6max7/

I also use ng-repeat to add input elements instead of just append them. Because ng-repeat have multiple children scopes. It make sure equipment_name value will have difference value in difference input.

```
    scope.equipments = scope.equipments || []; //prepare the array
    scope.equipments.push({}); //add new item

    var resourceNameInput = document.getElementsByClassName('resource-name-input');

    if(resourceNameInput.length === 0) {
      //add an ng-repeat element, but only one time  
      var inputTemplate = "<div class=\'resource-name-input input_wrapper\' ng-repeat=\'equipment in equipments\'><input ng-model=\'equipment.equipment_name\' type=\'text\' name=\'textInput\'></div>";

      //adds the new input above the previous
      angular.element(
          document.getElementById(childId))
          .append($compile(inputTemplate)(scope)
      );
    }
```